# Find the Price with Highest Volume Group-by on Datetime column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a Dataframe as below:

```
Datetime             Volume       Price
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1033         504
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1960         516
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1724         520
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1870         540
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1024         576
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1960         548
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1426         526
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1968         518
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1458         511
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1333         534
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1322         555
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1425         567
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1245         598
```

I want to find the price with highest volume group-by on Datetime column.

Result Dataframe as below:

```
Datetime             Volume       Price
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1960         516
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1968         518
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1458         511
```

Comment: something like `df.loc[df.groupby("Datetime")['Volume'].idxmax()]` should work (however if you may have duplicate maximum values and you want to return all such rows , then use the solution from the duplicate link).

Comment: You mean this will do.... idx = df.groupby(['Datetime'])['Volume'].transform(max) == df['Volume']..........df[idx]

Comment: Yes: `df[df["Volume"].eq(df.groupby("Datetime")['Volume'].transform("max"))]`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the quick help.